# Diablo 2: Hireling won't take potion?

Tags: diablo-ii

In Diablo 2, my hireling has fairly low health, so I'm trying to give her a health potion by dragging it onto her portrait. She thanks me, but refuses to drink the potion. In other words, the potion cannot be released from the mouse cursor onto the hireling's portrait.
Am I doing something wrong?

(My game version is 1.13c.)

[Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqpsd.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the hireling somehow neglected to follow me through my portal. She was therefore "too far away" to accept the potion.
Returning to town once more solved the issue; perhaps this is a minor bug.

Comment: It could also be a minor lag or something like that.

Comment: I tried several times through a period of about ten minutes. (This was a local, offline game.) @Roflcoptr

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the potion is not immediately visible because health doesn't immediately regenerate and the health-bar of the hireling feels like it's lagging behind. A rejuvenation potion should always have an immediate effect though.

If the hireling is poisoned, the health increase might not be visible either, as long as the poison negates the effect of the potion.

Normally your approach should work. As an alternative you can also try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *belt-slot* (usually 1-4) to directly give a potion from your belt to the hireling.

Comment: Releasing the potion on her portrait wasn't possible at all, it would simply "stick" to the cursor. With all my skeletons wandering around, it was hard to tell whether my hireling was still around. :-) Luckily I fixed the issue as per my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Didn't think about that, but makes sense.

Comment: The thing that made it very counterintuitive from the start was that she would still _thank me_. A "Where are you?" would have been more useful.